# Lots of DOM. Hidden vs display none

Tags: html, css, dom

If I have lots of DOM on the page and I set them all to display: none, the browser still reacts quickly (scrolling is fast, page feels snappy).

However, if I visibility: hidden the elements, the browser is as slow as if they were all drawn on the screen.

Can someone explain, in detail, why this is the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does opacity:0 have exactly the same effect as visibility:hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well in a way, they are drawn (but not really): The browser keeps space for them, so it must consider the items when laying out the visible ones.

See [MDC `visibility:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility):

> The box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still **affects layout**.  Descendants of the element will be visible if they have visibility:visible (this doesn't work in IE up to version 7).

If you specify `display: none` instead, the browser only as to care about and layout the visible ones. It does not have to take the others into account at all.

Depending on your visible/invisible ratio and the number of elements, this can make a difference.

Answer (score 15):

Imagine a painting.
You have a white background and start drawing an apple with a lot of details during one hour and then you completely cover it with another coat of white paint.
That's `visibility`.

`display:none` is like not drawing it from the start. Of course it's faster on first load.

There are drawbacks when you are using `display:none` though: when you are switching it back to `block` (or `inline` etc) you will have to start drawing the painting but using visibility the browser is just scratching the last coat of paint and it's back. So `visibility` is faster in this case.

But remember one thing when you are using `visibility:hidden` the element retains its position in the flow so **the elements around it won't budge**.

If you want a technical explanation check [David Baron's talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2_6bGNZ7bA#t=43m08s).

Answer (score 4):

This is quite interesting. So in essence `visibility: hidden` is technically the same as `opacity: 0`?

I'm no browser maker, but wouldn't it be a huge performance gain if elements that have visibility hidden weren't rendered or painted but instead painted as a transparent square with the dimensions of the element? At least in situations where the dimensions were known.

Answer (score 3):

With `visibility:hidden` they are all drawn on the screen, but they are not visible by the user.
Instead, with `display:none` they aren't drawn

Comment: I would clarify, for `visibility:hidden` they are rendered in the layout but **not** drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

With `visibility: hidden` their sizes have to be computed so the appropriate amount of space can be reserved for them. They are, effectively, still drawn.

Answer (score 2):

`display: none`: element will not be included in [render tree](https://web.dev/critical-rendering-path-render-tree-construction/)

`visibility: hidden`: element will be included in render tree (and layout process) but won't be painted in the end thus it is computationally more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Because `display: none` actually removes the elements from the DOM.  `visibility: hidden` merely makes them invisible, but they're still there.

You can notice the difference because form input fields that have `display: none` will simply not be included in the form when you submit it; input fields that merely have `visibility: hidden` set will still be there. Well, at least, that's my experience -- other browsers *may* behave differently.

Comment: Styles should not be affecting the DOM. The behaviour described here contradicts section "17.13.2 Successful controls" in the HTML 4.01 spec.

Comment: display: none; does not remove or in anyway affect an element's DOM representation.

Comment: I have verified that for some browsers, setting `display: none` dynamically *does* remove the elements from the DOM, regardless of what the spec says. That is apparently a performance optimization. I have seen it at least in Safari 6.2.2. Upvote parent.

Answer (score 0):

"the browser is as slow as if they were all drawn on the screen."

I think this is slow because the tag is still rendered, but isn't seen on the screen.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:none`, the browser does not initialize these elements nor render the content. This is not the case when using `visibility:hidden`, which initializes these elements but just hides them.

http://wiw.org/~frb/css-docs/display/display.html