# are elements with {visibility:hidden} present in the HTML DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are elements with the css property of `visibility:hidden` still present in the HTML DOM tree?

Comment: do you mean by default, no child tags in the body?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov by default

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718342/lots-of-dom-hidden-vs-display-none

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Thanks, I've already read that question but wasn't able to get a clear answer. I'm pretty sure that the elements with `visibility:hidden` is still present in the DOM, I just needed to confirm this

Comment: Just because an element has some style doesn't mean it disappears from the page. Even elements with `display: none` still appear on the page. (citation: a project involving a popup with display none=

Comment: Why not just test this for yourself using the browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for sure. The CSS is only applying styles to your HTML-DOM Elements. You can change the behaviour and even make it completly ivisible but the element still exists.