# Add link to button only using javascript/replacing window

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink

I am creating a text adventure game I want one of the option butttons to be a link to another webpage. So far I have:
'''

```
<article>
<div id="text"></article>
</div>
    
<input id="input" onkeydown='submitDogName(this)' placeholder='Type Your Dogs Name and Enter to Begin'>
<div id="buttonBox"></div>

<script>
var text = document.getElementById("text"); 
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttonBox');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
//this is the variable for the name of the character
var yerdog;



//this is how after we type in the character name and hit enter
//we will add the name to the variable, remove the input box and start our first scenario
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  console.log(input.value);
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    yerdog =  input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    advanceTo(scenario.two)
  }
};


//this changes the text and puts in your characters name
var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("Your dog", yerdog);
};



//this looks at the number of options we have set and creates enough buttons 
var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    buttonBox.innerHTML += "<button onClick="+buttonList[i][1]+">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</button>";
  };
};

//this is what moves the game along
var advanceTo = function(s) {
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};


// and append it to where you'd like it to go:
document.body.appendChild(element);


//this is the object that holds each scenario, the more you add the more options there are
//scenario = {}
var scenario = {
  one: {
    image: "", //dog
    text: "You have finally decided to take your dog out for a walk. You smile and pat your trusty 
           companion's head. What the dog's name?\n",
  },
  two: {
    image: "https://s9.postimg.org/9p8m7v1u7/6899639786_d517c4cce3_z.jpg", //house
    text: "Your dog yanks at the leash. You hear dogs barking and see an old abandoned house. Strangely, the door is wide open. What do you want to do?",
    buttons: [["Turn and run", "advanceTo(scenario.five)"]]


// and append it to where you'd like it to go:
document.body.appendChild(element);
    
    
  },
```

'''
Everything else works, I just want one of the buttons to be a hyperlink. I can't have it as a link at all times because I want the link to appear for only certain scenarios, not all the time. Or is it possible just to replace the window when the user gets to scenario 5??

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the button in an `<a>` tag, and then using a "hidden" attribute when you don't want it to show up?

Comment: How do you use a hidden attribute?

Comment: "hidden" is in and of itself and attribute. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718342/lots-of-dom-hidden-vs-display-none).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

To handle the `onClick` event for button and in handler function you can use `window.location.replace("https://example.com")` for some specific condition. It will navigate the user to given url page in same window.