# What's the behavior of an element with display: none?

Tags: html, css

I'm a little confused about the `display: none` property. Many articles ob the internet says that with display property set to **none** an element is not in the DOM tree. And that's the difference from `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden` which won't remove an element from the DOM and just make it invisible.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718378/20395932

> Because display: none actually removes the elements from the DOM.
> visibility: hidden merely makes them invisible, but they're still
> there.

From https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/css/visibility-hidden-vs-display-none/

> This is an important detail because with display:none, you are
> effectively removing the element from the DOM.

Also I read that

> The browser will not response to any events of element which uses
> either display: none or visibility: hidden.

But in React I set a ref to an element, set it's display porperty to none... and I still see that element in DOM in dev tools. Also I can call on-click handlers of this element via the ref.
Also I don't understand how `display: none` can remove any element from the DOM if it's just a CSS property and can't realy manipulate DOM.

As far as I understand the element with `display: none` is still in the DOM but it's just not rendered. But what about responsing to events?

Answer (score 3):

> ,,, with display property set to none an element is not in the DOM tree.

That's just wrong.

An element with display property set to none generates no box in the **box tree**. All descendant nodes in the DOM document also generate no boxes or text runs in the box tree.

---

In detail, `display:none` *is* somewhat magical. As well as generating no boxes for the DOM document sub-tree, it trumps positioning and floating in a way that other display properties don't, hides the entire DOM document sub-tree from the accessibility API, affects the processing of animations, probably other related stuff.

But it does not remove the element from the DOM document, nor remove or disable the event listeners or handlers from the element. But of course, since there's nothing rendered for the sub-tree, user interaction cannot fire events on those elements.

Comment: but about events of such element?

Comment: user can't interact with it so no user triggered events will fire.

Comment: It also has a few implications on the HTML side, basically the references to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#being-rendered with the most impressive one IMM: <object> content is unloaded when display:none, which could be said as actually affecting the DOM. Also, there can be events fired on hidden elements, for instance `oninvalid` would fire on hidden <input> when its parent <form> is submitted.