# visibility: hidden; AFTER opacity: 0;

Tags: visibility

I have a problem, i need to set the visibility of a div to "hidden" AFTER it has faded out.
My code so far:

```
$('#layer')
    .stop(true, true)
    .animate({
        opacity:"0",
    },1000);
```

The div is overlaying the whole page, so setting the opacity isn't a solution to make all the elements under the div clickable again.

But when I'm changing the code to this:

```
$('#layer')
    .stop(true, true)
    .animate({
        opacity:"0",
        visibility: "hidden"
    },1000);
```

It's faded out and invisible, but still there and interfering with the clickability of my objects under it.

Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Hope you can help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does opacity:0 have exactly the same effect as visibility:hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object should not be there, use `.fadeOut(1000)` instead.

Comment: Accepted - sorry, I thought it was the "arrow up" button, which can only be used after a reputation of 15 - I didn't know about the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In CSS, there's a key distinction between `visibility` and `display`. The visibility property will make something invisible while still factoring it into the display of the page. Saying `visibility: hidden` basically puts a cloak of invisibility over your object--other things can still bump in to it, but the object is just invisible.</strike>

So, you're looking for `display: none` which will remove it from the model entirely

JK, I learned something today!

Comment: Whoops, didn't thought about that. Thank you! But I used the solution of Charmander.

Comment: That is incorrect. `visibility: hidden` retains the element's position and sizing, possibly affecting the position and sizing of elements around it, but does not interfere with user interactions. http://jsfiddle.net/eKwJA/ The problem here is rather that of the use of `visibility` with `animate`; `visibility` cannot be animated. http://jsfiddle.net/eKwJA/1/