# visibility:hidden vs display:none vs opacity:0

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation, render

I'm currently starting on an animation project. In the project I'll have more than 40000 `div`s and animate them iteratively. If any of `div`s are in passive state (i.e. it's not animating at least for 2 seconds), I won't display them to increase animation performance.

The question is: which css property is the most suitable for this?

```
.passive1{
   display:none
}

.passive2{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.passive3{
    opacity:0;
}
```

And how can I measure rendering performance like fps, gpu usage?

Comment: If your animating 40,000 divs your going to have performance issues. Maybe you should look at using canvas/flash.

Comment: I think it's difficult to code in canvas such an animation because there is no transformation property in canvas. There is no translate, rotate functions in canvas. Or is there?

Comment: In SVG, [there is](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Does opacity:0 have exactly the same effect as visibility:hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

Comment: The better option is to generate SVG and then convert it to Canvas and delete old SVG from DOM. This will give you the performance boost. I have tested this with a nice performance boost in.

Comment: I would prefer WebGL in a large scale animation project like yours. Three.js also has an SVG render as fallback.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273076/1495728) will answer your first question (most likely `display:none` as the space is collapsed completely).

<strike>To your second question, tools such as [this](http://www.kaizou.org/2011/06/effectively-measuring-browser-framerate-using-css/) will probably be useful for you.</strike> However 40,000 divs sounds like way too many and you will probably have better performance using canvas or SVG (for example, using the [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) library as this handles animations - transformation, rotation, scale, etc.) for you.

Comment: The appropriate action would be to mark the question as a duplicate instead of linking to the duplicate's answer.

Comment: http://www.kaizou.org/2011/06/effectively-measuring-browser-framerate-using-css/ is a 404 and I have edited the answer. Edit accordingly.

Comment: fantastic answer!! admire how you answered the question first, then suggested a better approach.

Answer (score 359):

While all 3 properties make an element's box *seem* invisible, there are crucial differences between them:

| Property | Painted | In layout | Stacking context | Pointer events | Keyboard events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [`opacity: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) | No | **Yes** | **New** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| [`visibility: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) | No | **Yes** | *Varies* | No | No |
| [`display: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) | No | No | *Varies* | No | No |

- The "Painted" column indicates if the browser will paint the element's background (e.g. `background-image`), `#text` content, and so on.

  - An element cannot be painted without also participating in the page's layout, of course.
  - This is *No* for all 3 properties and values, as the browser won't need to paint the element's box as it's invisible.
- The "In layout" column indicates if the browser will compute the layout and dimensions of the element - along with any of its descendants not excluded from layout.

  - This is only *No* for `display: none;`, as with `opacity: 0;` and `visibility: hidden;` the browser will still determine the size of the element so it can correctly layout other elements relative to the current element (e.g. if you have `span.hidden { visibility: hidden; display: inline; }`).
- The "Stacking context" column indicates that any use of `opacity` (except `opacity: 1.0;`) will create a new stacking-context, which complicates use of the `position` property.
- The "Pointer events" column indicates if the element will respond to user-interaction from a pointing device, such as a mouse, touch-screen, stylus, etc.

  - e.g. with `visibility: hidden;` then the `:hover` state won't work, and clicking the same element won't apply `:focus` or `:active` either.
  - Additionally, the DOM won't raise any pointer events you'd handle in JavaScript (e.g. `visibility: hidden;` won't raise `mouseclick`, `touchstart`, etc - note that the `click` event can still be raised by certain elements, like `<button>` if invoked by the user using a non-pointer input method, such as with keyboard or voice (accessible) navigation means.

    - You can use `pointer-events: none;` to block pointer events, but **this won't block keyboard and other non-pointer input** and so should not be used to disable an element because the user can still use the keyboard to interact with it (especially `<button>`, `<input />`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`).
- The "Keyboard events" column indicates if the element can be interacted-with using keyboard navigation (and possibly other navigation means).

  - This includes smart-device (smartphones' and tablets') browsers' "Prev/Next Field" buttons for navigating `<form>` elements (as this uses `tabindex`).
  - Unlike how pointer-events can be disabled in CSS using `pointer-events: none;`, there is no CSS property to disable keyboard interaction.

---

This table shows a more complete comparison between the main values of those 3 properties:

| Property | Painted | In layout | Stacking context | Pointer events | Keyboard events | Animatable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Opacity** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `opacity: 0;` | No | **Yes** | **New** | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| `opacity: 0.1;` | **Yes** | **Yes** | **New** | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| `opacity: 0.9;` | **Yes** | **Yes** | **New** | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| `opacity: 1;` | **Yes** | **Yes** | *Varies* | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| **Visibility** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `visibility: hidden;` | No | **Yes** | *Varies* | No | No | Yes, with caveats |
| `visibility: visible;` | **Yes** | **Yes** | *Varies* | **Yes** | **Yes** | Yes, with caveats |
| **Display** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `display: none;` | No | No | *Varies* | No | No | No |
| `display: contents;` | Text and children only | Text and children only | *Varies* | **Yes** | **Yes** | No |
| **Other** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `pointer-events: none;` | N/A | N/A | N/A | No | **Yes** | No |

- The "Animatable" column indicates if that property can be used with a CSS transition (`transition:`) or CSS animation (`@keyframes`).

  - Crucially, the `display:` property *cannot be animated*, which is why we can't use a `@keyframes` timeline to completely hide an element after the animation is complete.

    - But curiously, we *can* animate the `visibility:` property despite being non-continuous, [albeit with caveats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#interpolation).
- Also, don't get confused by the similarly-named [`backface-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) and [`content-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content-visibility) properties.

  - `backface-visibility` is only applicable to 3D `transform` operations.
  - `content-visibility` [is an optimization to speed-up page rendering](https://web.dev/content-visibility/) during initial page-load, but requires CSS Containment first, which is out-of-scope for this QA.

Comment: I should print this table and stick it on the edge of my computer monitor.

Comment: Perfect answer! Very helpful.

Comment: Explanation couldn't have been better

Comment: Note that it IS possible to use e.g. jQuery to trigger a click on elements that don't consume click

Answer (score 9):

`display:none` will hide the whole element and remove that from layout space whereas `visibility:hidden` hides an element but take up the same space as before.
Opacity can be used if you want to create transparency or fade effect.

Answer (score 9):

Performance will be an issue if display:none or visibility:hidden is used since they trigger paint and layout in most browsers which means your browser will redraw the viewport whenever those two changes so I will recommend opacity but still for that number of divs it will still be not performant as expected you can try webgl using a library called html-gl which render your divs in webgl check https://github.com/PixelsCommander/HTML-GL

Comment: this is the correct answer. Opacity 0 solves most the issues

Comment: why would visibility change trigger a layout ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 because of how the particular browser is implemented to know which property change trigger paint/layout/compositing check here https://csstriggers.com/

Comment: thanks! this is a great resource 

Answer (score 7):

Here is a compilation of verified information from the various answers.

Each of these CSS properties is in fact unique. In addition to rendering an element not visible, they have the following additional effect(s):

1. **Collapses** the space that the element would normally occupy
2. Responds to **events** (e.g., click, keypress)
3. Participates in the **taborder**

```
                     collapse events taborder
opacity: 0              No     Yes     Yes
visibility: hidden      No     No      No
visibility: collapse    *      No      No
display: none          Yes     No      No

* Yes inside a table element, otherwise No.
```

got from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden/273076#273076)

Answer (score 4):

`display:none` because the divs are taken out of the flow then, thus their position does not have to be calculated.

That being said, 40000 divs sounds crazy. Did you consider the alternatives like HTML5 canvas or SVG?

Comment: Thanks. But you didn't say anyting about my second question. `how can I measure rendering performance like fps, gpu usage?`

Comment: That's because I don't have experience with that. But in a quick Google search some browser plugins showed up, did you try any?

Comment: I found one. Using shift+esc showing up a task manager which shows memory, cpu, fps etc.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the Chrome taskmanager. And of course it measures everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometime i use visibility and opacity together to achieve effect to avoid click event

e.g.

normal state/element removed from screen:

```
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
transition: all .3s;
```

hover state/element on screen:

```
visibility:visible;
opacity:1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread whilst investigating a hover: bug in Safari mobile

Confirming that `opacity: 0` is a valid approach (it is in my case, thanks all). `opacity: 0` fixes it enough to be workable (still requires an annoying js redraw on screen rotate [width change]).

Background info on the bug I fixed with `opacity: 0`:
The hover is on a li containing a div that is revealed when hovering (or single touch on mobile) a calendar entry.  Really random working/not working in Safari mobile - and even weirder the behavior changes on a screen rotate++ [nb no media queries involved so not that].

So annoying as otherwise works in all other browsers I've tried.