# Prevent children divs from moving while div toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new and have I think very simple problem to solve.

I have 4 buttons to `show/hide` each panel. What should I do to prevent child divs from moving to te left while hiding some `div`?
I prefer them to stay at the initial position.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
    <button class="panel-button" data-panel="panel1">1</button>
    <button class="panel-button" data-panel="panel2">2</button>
    <button class="panel-button" data-panel="panel3">3</button>
    <button class="panel-button" data-panel="panel4">4</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="panel1">1</div>
        <div id="panel2">2</div>
        <div id="panel3">3</div>
        <div id="panel4">4</div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
        $(function() {
            $('.panel-button').on('click',function(){
                var panelId = $(this).data('panel');// attr('data-panel')
                $('#'+panelId).toggle();
            });
        });
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 420px;
}

.wrapper > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply css rule `opacity = 0;` to the `div`, instead of hiding it.
Like this:

```
$('.panel-button').on('click',function(){
    var pnl = $('#' + $(this).data('panel'));
    pnl.css('opacity', pnl.css('opacity') == '0' ? '1' : '0');
});
```

Solution for clickability issue:

```
$('.panel-button').on('click',function(){
    var pnl = $('#' + $(this).data('panel'));
    if(pnl.is(':visible'))
        $('<div></div>').appendTo(pnl).width(pnl.width());
    else
        pnl.next().remove();
    pnl.toggle();
});
```

Comment: While this is a valid solution, their might be problems when there are  clickable items inside. The user would still be able to clik them.

Comment: No need for hacky javascript, use CSS `visiblity` instead combined with jquery's toggleClass() (see the other answer).

Answer (score 1):

But still you can use another approach

You can use the `visibility` property in CSS to achieve this as shown in the below Fiddle link : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nfgpxvc3/)

JS Snippet:

```
$(function() {

  $('.panel-button').on('click',function(){
    var panelId = $(this).data('panel');// attr('data-panel')
    console.log($('#'+panelId).css('visibility'));
    if($('#'+panelId).css('visibility') === 'hidden') {    
      $('#'+panelId).css('visibility','visible');
    }
    else {
      $('#'+panelId).css('visibility','hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS [`visibility`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731049/visibilityhidden-vs-displaynone-vs-opacity0) is designed to keep the space a DOM object occupies, but not actually rendering it. Opacity changes its appearance, but not its behavior (eg. still clickable).

So instead of .toggle(), combine `visibility` with jQuery's [`.toggleClass()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp):

[jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ndn5vbqr/)

```
$(function() {
        $('.panel-button').on('click',function(){
            var panelId = $(this).data('panel');// attr('data-panel')
            $('#'+panelId).toggleClass('hideMe');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I took into consideration also toggleClass solution, but for me it doesn't work.
.hidden {
 opacity:0;
    var panelId = $('#' + $(this).data('panel'));
    panelId.toggleClass('hidden');
}

Comment: @kuba0506 The jsFiddle example clearly demonstrates it works perfectly