# hide div on mouseenter — but keep it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs — when mouseenter divA it should disappear and divB should appear. When mouseleave divB divA should show again and divB disappear. I’ve used this code to achieve it:

```
$("#divA").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $("#divA").hide();
        $("#divB").show();
    });
    $("#divB").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $("#divA").show();
        $("#divB").hide();
    });`
```

The only problem is that when divA hides another div (which used to sit under it) enters his place … So the question is if there’s a way to let divA disappear visually but not “physically”?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using `display` property, try using `opacity` property to do it:

```
$("#divA").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#divA").css("opacity", 0);
    $("#divB").css("opacity", 1);
});

$("#divB").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#divA").css("opacity", 1);
    $("#divB").css("opacity", 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34529598/9063935) answer for more details on the differences between `display`, `visiblility` and `opacity`. In the link, what you're looking for is the ones which have a tick under `occupies space`.

Essentially you want to set its css property

```css
element.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

which visually hides the element, but it can still be interacted with.

Comment: Thanks a ton! 
When using  $("#divA").css({"opacity":"0"}) and $("#divA").css({"opacity":"1"}) it works!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something related to the css property called `visibility`. This property hides the element but 'keeps it there'.

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_visibility.asp

And looks like you are using jQuery. So I searched a bit and I found this answer that explains precisely how to change the visibility of an element by using jQuery.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614662/2250437

Might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `hide()` and `show()`, try setting CSS `visibility` property as below:

```
$("#divA").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#divA").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#divB").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
$("#divB").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#divA").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#divB").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```