# Stop ":hover" elements from holding their state when animated away from cursor with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

I'm having an issue where elements do not lose their `:hover` when the element is animated away from the mouse via jQuery `animate()`.

The `:hover` stays applied until the mouse is moved. Is there any way to stop this behavior?
It seems to happen in IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: Could you give us some code?

Comment: *"Is there any way to stop this behavior?"* not that i can think of, i don't think there's anything you can do with javascript that would force the browser to re-evaluate whether or not the mouse is over an element. You could remove the :hover and replace it with a hover class, then add/remove the class with javascript that way you can remove the class when you animate to simulate the mouse leaving it(though, the leave event will be triggered, so that likely wouldn't be needed either)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried ? Perhaps prepare a fiddle ?

Comment: @SAFEERN http://jsfiddle.net/2wYxW/

Comment: Actually my suggestion won't work either, because the mouseleave event also won't be triggered unless you move the mouse.

Comment: Had the similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886903/css-hover-works-only-when-mouse-moves the only viable answer is to check mouse position against element position

Comment: If it can be assumed that with every animate the element would lose its hover state, then why not set a callback on animate to remove said hover state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to remove the hover state, but it may not work on all browsers and has its drawbacks.

The secret weapon is the CSS property `pointer-events`. If you set it's value to `none`, then the element no longer receives mouse events. If it's in a hovered state it loses that state (tested in Chrome and Safari).

Removal of the hover state only works while the mouse pointer is still over the element. So if you do that before the animation starts you will see either no hover state at all or a short flash, depending on the browser.

If that's a problem for you, you need to calculate a timeout or use a `progress` handler for `.animate()` to get the right moment.

Comment: Although this wouldn't work with my application, needing IE support, I feel it is the most accurate answer to the question posed. I ended up adding a class via Javascript.

Comment: Hey Guys, I've successfully overcome the problem of using animate.css with bootstrap dropdowns using the pointer-events: none; trick thanks a million.  However this does not work with <IE11. 
 I figures since I'm applying the animation via jQuery I should be able to stop the :hover problem at the same time, but can not figure out how (it is beyond my knowledge).  the script to implement the animation is as follows, any help would be appreciated: `subMenu.addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
     setTimeout(function(){
      subMenu.removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');
     },500);`

Answer (score 0):

you can give another function or event using time out function.

```
$("#box").one("mouseenter",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).css('color','green');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $this.css('color','red');
    },300);
})
```

this type of method work without leaving hover state. I don't know this type of method work for you..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  The jquery animate function moves the element out from under the mouse cursor and thus does not receive the mousemove or mouseleave event that would reset the `:hover` state to off.

I found that I couldn't use the CSS pseudo-class selectors, and instead had to rely on the jquery `hover()` api method to add/remove a separate CSS class manually.

```
$('li.hoverable').hover(
    function () { $(this).addClass('hovering'); },
    function () { $(this).removeClass('hovering'); });
```

Then later

```
// animate back to the final position
elem.animate({ top: 0, left: 0 }, 400, "easeInOutCubic",
    function () { elem.removeClass('hovering'); });
```