# Refresh the browser hover effect after a DOM change

Tags: javascript, css, hover, mouseover

I've got an element whose css is altered under `:hover`. I've also got some javascript that changes the height of the element. However if the javascript fires while the `:hover` state is  active the state remains even though the height change moves the element out from underneath the mouse.

Also since the javascript is fired by a click event within the element. This effect occurs on touch screens too.

I want to know if there's some way of coping with this issue. Can I force the browser to re-calculate hover (or mouseover etc)? Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript), I'm not optimistic.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aidanewen/4PmHJ/) to demonstrate the issue.

I guess if the worst comes to the worst I could do it all manually with classes, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` and `DOMAttrModified`. But that sounds like a pain and may even be costly in terms of javascript (I'll have to manually identify whether the mouse sits within the bounds of my elements).

UPDATE

OK, so I really can't touch `DOMAttrModified`, the performance hit is [massive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events#Performance).

Comment: What is the desired effect - the DIV should be in constant motion back and forth?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter the effect I'm creating is a tab closing following a new search - the search button is contained within the tab. My fiddle is just an example.

Comment: I don't think there's currently a viable solution besides some JS hack, had similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886903/css-hover-works-only-when-mouse-moves

Answer (score 2):

element.parentNode.replaceChild(element, element);

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseleave` event is never firing if you just leave your cursor there because technically you're not leaving the div that has the hover state.

I would recommend not using `mouseover`. It's a pain. Use `mouseenter` instead.

I do not know of any viable solutions, other than working around it by testing if the div is in it's `:hover` state, and then creating a separate function with a timeout to return it to it's original position, size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure at all if this is viable in a real-life scenario, but this is only hack I could see. Basically on `window.mouseMove` event save current coordinates of the mouse and then on `setInterval` compare it to coordinates of the element to determine whether element is "hovered". I have to use setInterval because otherwise unless mouse moves - no event happens:

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');
var mouseX, mouseY;

window.onmousemove=function(event){
    ev = event || window.event;
    mouseX = ev.pageX;
    mouseY = ev.pageY;
}

setInterval(function() {

    if (mouseX >=el.offsetLeft && mouseX <= el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth &&
        mouseY >=el.offsetTop && mouseX <= el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) {

        el.style.top = '200px';
        el.style.left = '200px';
        el.className = 'div_hover';


    } else {

        el.style.top = '50px';
        el.style.left = '50px';
        el.className = '';

    }


},1000)
```

I've used 1000 interval to demonstrate the effect **([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/4PmHJ/2/))** this can be adjusted. But again, I am not sure how feasible is pulling this info on setInterval