# How to prevent position change when another object is hidden

Tags: jquery, css

I made 4 boxes and want to hide the third one with jQuery. When I do that, the fourth one moves next to the second one, but that's not what I want. I want the fourth one to stay where it is. What should I do?

```js
$('.list_ch3').click(function(){
     $('.list_ch3').hide('slow');
    });
```

```css
.list {
    display:flex; flex-direction: 
}
.list li{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: pink; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-left: 15px; 
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list" >
  <li class="list_ch1">list item 1</li>
  <li class="list_ch2">list item 2</li>
  <li class="list_ch3">list item 3</li>
  <li class="list_ch4">list item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `$('.list_ch3').css('opacity',0);`

Comment: Thanks that's a way but does there is other way to do with css code so that I do with jquery with other effects ,like fade in fade out etc.

Answer (score 2):

`.hide()` sets the css `display:` property to `none`, which makes the element disappear and not take up space.

If you want the element to be hidden, but still occupy space, set it's css `visibility` property to `hidden`:

```
$('.list_ch3').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
```

Example:

```js
$('#foo').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'visibility' : 'hidden' });
});

$('#bar').click(function(){
  $(this).hide('slow');
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Click: Visibility Hidden</div>
<div id="bar">Click: Display None</div>
<div id="baz">Baz</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the visibility to hidden

```
$('.list_ch3').click(function(){
    $('.list_ch3').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
});
```

.hide() set display: none, which removes its space, visibility: hidden preserves the space

**Update**
If you still want the fading effect, try this:

```
$('.list_ch3').click(function(){
    $('.list_ch3').animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00xqfe9o/)

Comment: Just an FYI - "opacity" and "visibility" [aren't the same thing in css land](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden) (which i just discovered as well). The primary difference is `opacity : 0` is still "tabable" and "clickable" whereas "hidden" is not. :)