# Protractor/Selenium with Angular overlay, other element would receive click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

our app has an angular overlay that is always in the dom (although not always visible).. and sometimes when I attempt to click on elements on the page, Selenium throws an error...

> Element is not clickable at point (544, 297). Other element would
>   receive the click: div class="overlay" style="transition-property:
>   opacity; -webkit-transition-property: opacity; transition-duration:
>   300ms; -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms; transition-timing-function:
>   ease-in-out; -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; display:
>   block; opacity: 0;">

Does anyone else experience this? webdriver .isDisplayed always reports that it is false, even when it is still inhibiting clicks.

I have written some code that attaches to protractor's waitForAngular function that checks for various states of the overlay's dom element (to wait until it has a display: attribute with value "none"). This helps a lot and I no longer experience this issue unless the browser is executing in the background. If the browser is not in foreground, then I hit the overlay issue very frequently. While protractor is waiting (based on my wait for angular override), if I bring the browser to foreground, then the test immediately begins continuing to execute and the dom state changes for the overlay.

Would love any thoughts from people with insight.

I assume the .isDisplayed not working properly seems to be a webdriver issue. And I also assume that the overlay being stuck in a specific dom state in the background to be an angular issue.

Comment: Does eliminating the time taken for the transition make any difference?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue.  Did you ever figure out a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

By what is in your css properties, your element has `opacity: 0;`

accordantly to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273076/652579), elements with `opacity: 0` still receive events, so your overlay is not completely hidden.

I'd suggest you to use other css properties to hide your overlay such as `visibility: hidden` or `display:none;` instead.

Comment: Do you believe that would solve that the overlay would function properly in the background while scripts are running? Thank you for the response.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  Have you tried changing it to display:none

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. The question asks about an overlay