# Multiple Class Selectors with !important :: CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, css-specificity

Here is my problem:  I want to make a thing, where when you hover over one object, it disappears, but another object appears.  I tried this for my code:

```css
h1.title:hover + .ps{
    visibility: visible;
}
h1.title:hover !important{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
.ps{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please add your html code also

Comment: You can use `!important` with css properties not css selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you want smth like this :

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/3hpaxkme/)**

IMPORTANT : `h1.title:hover !important{` this is **not** correct , the `!important` must be inside the `{}` and after the css properties for example `opacity:1!important`

code added 
PS i used opacity instead of visibility...but you can change it if you want

html :

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <p>Other text</p>
</div>
```

css :

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}
h1 { 
font-size:40px;
color:red;
line-height:48px;
margin:0;
transition:0.3s;

}
.container p {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  font-size:35px;
  line-height:40px;
  color:blue;
  margin:0;
  transition:0.3s;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
.container h1:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
.container h1:hover + p {
  opacity:1;
}
```

to see differences between opacity and visibility [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

the fact is that if you use `opacity` the object disappears ( fades out ) but it's still there ( occupies space ) and if you have another object in the same place you **can** access it.

but  in the case of `visibility` , it does the same exact thing as `opacity` but you **can't** access the element behind it.

in your case, the h1 title is the one triggering the hover effect and so...even though you hide it, you still need to be able to ' touch ' it, that's why you need opacity. and that's why if you use `visibility` the effect will not be so nice

**BUT**

if you want to use `visibility` , remove the transition , because visibility has a  **binary** setting (visible/hidden) not a **calculable ** property (1,0) , and so `transition` doesn't work with visibility

and then use this code :

```
.container p {
    visibility:hidden;
}

.container:hover h1 {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.container:hover  h1+p {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: It seemed to work with opacity instead of visibility.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Is there any extra code I need to put in to be able to substitute opacity with visibility like the `z-index`?

Comment: edited my answers with a complete explanation :) hope i explained ok

Comment: Thanks!  That works.  The only problem is that it flashes like I am hovering over it and then moving my mouse away, only repeated and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to achieve what you want.

```css
div {
    display: none;
}
    
a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
a:hover {
   display: none;

}
```

```html
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javacript (it's best to use jquery – it just makes things simpler).

```js
$("p.show").hide();
function hide() {
  $("p.show").show();
  $("p.hide").hide();
}
```

```css
p.show {
  visibility: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='hide' onmouseover='hide()'>Hover on me</p>
<p class='show'>Done!</p>
```