# What is the difference between visibility: hidden and transform: scale(0,0)?

Tags: html, css

Is there any difference between `visibility: hidden` and `transform: scale(0,0)`? Both give same results?

Comment: Yes, but the differences only matter in certain contexts. There isn't enough information in your question to tell which, if any, are relevant.

Comment: Transform literally reshapes the element, here is what the other common methods for hiding an element do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden/273076#273076

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `visibility` of an element to `hidden` it is hidden but still takes up space.

If you set the `visiblity` to `collapse` it will not take up space and will behave the same as `display:none`. But `collapse` can only be used on table elements.

`transform: scale(0,0)` will just set the size to 0,0 meaning css properties like `float` or `clear` will still take affect on other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they both work same

`Visiblity: hidden` The element is invisible (but still takes up space).

`transform: scale(0,0)` It will changes the appearance visually; the actual dimensions of the original object are maintained.