# Adding a Class vs Removing a Class to Show Elements on a Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Current Design

In a website I am designing I have a number of elements that initially will appear hidden, until the user *needs* to see them. For example they have scrolled to a desired height on the page.

Currently this works by JavaScript adding a class `line.classList.add('show-header-line');`

Which in CSS will be defined next to the main styling for the element. This `show` variant of the class will only contain attributes required to make the element visible `opacity: 1`. The main styling for the element will contain the opposite attributes required to hide the element initially `opacity: 0.`

## The Alternative

Of course this could work the other way around. With a class designed to hide the element initially being set in the html, then to be removed when required by JavaScript.

*HTML*

`<div class="header-line hide-header-line" />`

*JS*

`line.classList.remove('hide-header-line');`

## Note

Of course I could add and remove styles directly (without the need for extra classes) in the JavaScript, but this seems much worse. Regarding a lack of separation of concerns.

## Question

My **current approach** means the resulting rendered DOM is littered with elements that have *main style* class and a *show* class. **The alternative** means my html file is littered with elements with a *main style* class and a *hide* class. Which is considered better practice? Is there another cleaner way I could be doing this?

Comment: From what side do you start to eat a banana? I think it is just a matter of taste. I prefer to hide elements I don't want to show and then add `.open` class to them. You should think of something like what if user will have javascript disabled, do you want the items to be visible or hidden...

Comment: @JavaEvgen You make a good point. With JavaScript disabled the site becomes pretty difficult to use. Right now I am just planning to a `<noscript>` tag to fix this (but have not done this yet). It is a shame this a use case we still must consider.

Answer (score 1):

I would **strongly** suggest against using `opacity:0` for this, rather use `display: none`. The reason being that an element with `opacity: 0` still occupies space in the markup, whereas `display: none` will add the element to the DOM, but it won't be rendered in the markup (if that makes sense).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden/273076#273076) is a more detailed explanation

Also, an example using the scroll pass certain point you said, this is how I would do it, **note** code is untested.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  document.querySelector('#navigation').classList[this.scrollTop > 200 ? 'add' : 'remove']('fixed-nav');
});
```

css

```
.fixed-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess I have used opacity because I want to transition the elements in. Which I didn't think you can do with a display?

Comment: @MichaelHancock yes you are right, you can't make a kind of fade in/out effect using `display` property