# css change hidden to visible on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to hide some rating text on the page until I hovered over it.

I am novice css + javascript coder and I was testing some css override code (eg using a chrome browser with stylebot extension) when viewing a web, which means you can only modify css. I did not find a way to do this with css **visibility** attribute but using **opacity** works fine see code shown below.  I could not find anything that explains why css **visibility** will not change when I hover over the area. Just curious if anyone can explain it. Is it possible to do with **visibility** in only css?

If I were doing **visibility** changes via javascript would this behavior be identical as pure css? I saw few questions on stackoverflow.com asking what looked like similar questions but did follow them. Just curious.

(Edit: I first tried **display** then tried **visibility**. I realize space is kept with visibility but is hover disabled?).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.mydiv1 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
div.mydiv1:hover {
    visibility:visible;
}

div.ratingValue {
    opacity: 0
}
div.ratingValue:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
Opacity:
<div class=ratingValue>
  Opacity example
<p />
</div>
Visibility:
<div class=mydiv1>
    Visibility example
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry I meant visibility attribute not display. I will adjust the question thanks @ovokuro

Comment: thanks @JemiSalo that expained it and I assume that would be no different for javascript.

Comment: I voted to close question I hope that means answered not delete.

Answer (score 2):

See the specs:

> **`visibility: hidden`** The element box is invisible (not drawn), but still affects layout as normal. Descendants of the element will be visible if they have `visibility` set to `visible`. The element cannot receive focus (such as when navigating through tab indexes).

---

> **`display: none`** Lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use `none`, all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree.

Comment: thanks and further reading confirmed that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden