# fade out transition for .mouseout using .animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that when you hover, another div shows up. They aren't parent/child or wrapped, so I used a script to get this to work the easiest I could and to have what I needed. With .mouseover the hover div slowly appears which is what I want.

**My issue is** getting the .mouseout to make the hover div slowly disappear and stay gone. I've tried different variations but the closest I got is to make the div slowly fade away, but it pops back up after the delay I had set.

I'm very new to js, really no experience at all. I wrote the first part of this code which works but the .mouseout is what I'm having issues with.

Here's my code:

```
$("#show_stats1 h1").mouseover(function() { $(".stat-1_info").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 200); });

$("#show_stats1 h1").mouseout(function() { $(".stat-1_info").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "hidden"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 200); });
```

I know it's probably simple, but I don't know much if anything about js.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="show_stats1" class="stats">
    main, visible div
</div>


<div class="stat-1_info" style="visibility:hidden;">
    hidden div to be shown on hover
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yt3h9xnf/

Comment: can you add your ```html``` code in the question. More than that give the code in https://jsfiddle.net/ .It will help to give the answer for your question.

Comment: You're immediately setting `visibility: hidden` on the element...

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, try using `$(".stat-1_info").show();` and `.hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.animate()` method with either `opacity` or `visibility`. There is no reason to use both.

If you can't figure out which one to use read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden/273076#273076).

```js
$("#show_stats1 h1").mouseover(function() { 
  $(".stat-1_info").animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
});

$("#show_stats1 h1").mouseout(function() { 
  $(".stat-1_info").animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
});
```

```css
.stat-1_info {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="show_stats1" class="stats">
    <h1>main, visible div</h1>
</div>

<div class="stat-1_info">
    hidden div to be shown on hover
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make it simple by using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` with `sec` as parameter. This will take care of the time you want to see the text and want to disappear.
2. Use `display:none;` which is latest and best in market now than using `visibility` property.

[fadeIn()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

[fadeOut()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show_stats1 h1").mouseover(function() {
    $(".stat-1_info").fadeIn(3000); // Choose your own time(3sec)
  });

  $("#show_stats1 h1").mouseout(function() {
    $(".stat-1_info").fadeOut(2000); // Choose your own time(2sec)
  });
});
```

```css
.stats_container {
  width: 310px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.stats {
  width: 300px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 15px 0px -3px 0px;
}

.stats h1 {
  text-align: left;
}

.stats h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 260px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.stats h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 9.5pt;
  font-size: 9.5pt;
}

.stat-1_info {
  top: -50px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.stat-1_info {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 334px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stats_container">
  <div id="show_stats1" class="stats">
    <h1>Strength:</h1>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="stat-1_info" style="display:none;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pretium magna et velit dignissim, a placerat nisi rutrum. Vestibulum odio ipsum, rutrum a ex ac, fringilla fermentum ante. Donec nec elit molestie massa finibus pulvinar non nec lacus. Nullam
  ipsum nulla, sodales non ornare et, accumsan a sem. Donec tempus leo non laoreet viverra. Vestibulum ac nunc sem. Aenean vitae convallis velit, non molestie augue. Curabitur tristique eleifend mi, malesuada fringilla erat tristique imperdiet.
</div>
```