# Render conditionally a component without losing "empty" space - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am wondering how can i render a component conditionally without losing its space . Basically i want to remove the shift of the other components because of this `div`
[image]

Any suggestions ?
Here is part of my code :

```
   const [displayFeedbackMessage, setDisplayFeedbackMessage ] = useState();

 useEffect(() => {
        setDisplayFeedbackMessage(
            <div>
            {
                displaySelectionResult &&
                selected > 0 &&
                <div>
                    {Pluralize("document", selected, true)}
                    {" "}selected out of{" "}
                    {Pluralize("document", available, true)}
                    {" "}available.
                </div>
            }

            {
                displayActionResult &&
                <div>
                    {Pluralize("document", actioned, true)}
                    {" "} downloaded out of{" "}
                    {Pluralize("document", requested, true)}
                    {" "}requested.
                </div>
            }
            </div>
       
        )

    },[selected, available, actioned, requested])

   return (

        <div>{displayFeedbackMessage}</div>

    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `visibility`  style to your div contain message, then set it `visible : hidden`  to show or hide it

```
style={{ height: '50px', visibility : condition ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}
```

Comment: the style should be setted to the `div`  into the `return` or ... ?

Comment: in your case i think you should put default value in const [displayFeedbackMessage, setDisplayFeedbackMessage ] = useState(null);

Comment: then <div style={{ opacity : !!displayFeedbackMessage ? '1' : '0' }}>{displayFeedbackMessage}</div>

Comment: btw how you can bold your comment sir :D

Comment: " ` "  with this symbol you have to wrap your word that you want to highlight . But further to the discussion . This method that you have suggested does not work . I mean it does but the shift still persist

Comment: how about set a fixed height for that div contain message , to make sure if Message have value or not, it still have that height ? @PandaMastr

Comment: `<div style={{ height: '50px' , visibility : displayFeedbackMessage ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}}>{displayFeedbackMessage}</div>` update your answer with this and i will mark it as correct . Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

You could use the styles **visibility** (hidden or visible) or **opacity** (0 or 1). They are a bit different as you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273076/1712944).

Answer (score 0):

Visibilty for hiding the View and display "none" for hiding it without taking any space. I remember this is correct?

Comment: It's unclear whether this is an answer or question. Please rephrase and be affirmative if you meant this as an answer. Ideally give an explicit code.

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Try to avoid the impression that you are asking a question instead of answering. If this IS meant as a question please delete it.